# Windows: How to configure multiple versions of Python to work together?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-2.7, python-3.7

I installed Python 2.7 a long time ago on my PC (I am running Windows 10). Today I decided to install Python 3.7, but after typing 'python' into the command prompt the console printed 'python 2.7...'

I have no idea as to what I should do. Would this be a problem with my path configuration? I considered uninstalling python 2.7 but I still want it installed on my computer.

Comment: try `python3` - on Linux I have `python`, `python2`, `python2.7`, `python3`, `python3.6`, `python3.7`, and the same with `pip` - it is normal. So I can easily choose which one to use.

Comment: @furas This returns 'python3.7 is not recognized...'

Comment: do you have `python3` ? `python3.7`, etc. is natural on Linux. I assume you use Windows so you may have only `python` and `python3` and maybe `py`, `py3` or something similar.

Comment: @furas I have python3.7, python2.7, and python3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows)

Comment: Do you need all python instances to be available from the command line? Normally, if you install multiple Python into separate locations, they work together (or apart) just fine - what problem exactly are you looking for a solution to? (and yes, the path configuration is causing your situation, but I'm trying to find out what your resulting problem is)

Answer (score 8):

## Configure multiple Python versions on Windows

Python 3.3 introduced the [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows). Rather than using `python.exe`, call `py` and select the version with flags:

```
py -2.7
```

```
py -3
```

System-wide installations of Python 3.3 and later will put the launcher on your PATH.

### Note on Virtual Environments (new in Python 3.5)

> If the launcher is run with no explicit Python version specification, and a virtual environment (created with the standard library [venv](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/venv.html#module-venv) module or the external virtualenv tool) active, the launcher will run the virtual environment’s interpreter rather than the global one. To run the global interpreter, either deactivate the virtual environment, or explicitly specify the global Python version.

#### Outdated Method (not recommended)

1. **Rename executables** - After installing multiple versions, change the names of the executables. For example, for Python 2.7, under the installation folder, rename `python.exe` to `python27.exe` and rename Python 3.7 from `python.exe` to `python37.exe`. Then on the command line, select the version by entering `python27` or `python37`. Whichever version is preferred, could be left as just `python`.
2. **Add Path Environment Variables** - For example, on Windows 10, go to the Windows menu and search for "environment variables" and click <kbd>edit the system environment variables</kbd>. In the System Properties dialog, click <kbd>Environment Variables...</kbd>. Under "System variables", select "Path". Click <kbd>Edit...</kbd>. Click <kbd>New</kbd> and add the first entry below. Click <kbd>New</kbd> again for each Path variable entry.

   - `C:\Python27`
   - `C:\Python27\Scripts`
   - `C:\Python37`
   - `C:\Python37\Scripts`

This will enable Python and pip. Be sure that paths match your actual installation directories.

Comment: Don't rename executables, but instead provide aliases, on Windows you can use batch files (or similar) like `python2.7.bat` and put them somewhere on the path to start the appropriate Python. Renaming will cause issues when updating or when other applications rely on `python.exe` being called `python.exe`. Adding all Python instances to the path also isn't needed. However, I would recommend using environment variables in your batch file to let each Python know where it is supposed to look for stuff. However, does OP even need all Python to work from the command line?

Comment: @Grismar Fair point. See update regarding the Python Launcher for Windows.

Comment: I'll leave the comment, but removed the down-vote, as you now do give the answer I think is closest to what OP should be considering (depending on their actual problem)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

I have been using it and is working well for me. Some of the handy features of pyenv are

- It allows installing multiple version on python easily
- It allows switching python version with one command in global, shell or folder level
- It also allows creating virtual env using [virtualevn](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv) extension

Answer (score 1):

You Can Configure The Python2 & python3 In Windows PC Like This:

1. First Of All Install Python 2 & Python 3 in windows PC in C directory like this:
   C:\Python27  --> For Python2
   C:\Python39  --> For Python3
   [image: Example:]

After Installing Both Packages Go To Their Respective Folders And Copy **python.exe** & Paste In The Same Directory and rename the **python - Copy** with **python2**(In python27 folder) & **python3**(In python39 folder)

Python2:
[image: Python2]

Python3:
[image: Python3]

And Then Set Environment Vairable Like This:
[image]

All Done Now You Can Run Any Script Which May Compatible With Python2 or Python3 :)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use virtual environment. Soon or later you would you might get [dependency problems](https://medium.com/knerd/the-nine-circles-of-python-dependency-hell-481d53e3e025).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.